# Direct seeding in straw bale?

Tags: germination

This is my second year going with a straw bale garden. I am direct seeding several plants (e.g., cucumbers, green beans), and I've typically followed the standard advice of seeding them in a 2" layer of potting soil atop the bale. However, I was wondering whether I couldn't just dig a little hole in the bale, place some potting soil in it in order to save on potting soil, and then put the seed in that little soil pocket, kind of like what I do with transplants. It seems like it should work, but I just don't see anyone doing it. Any thoughts or experiences with this approach?

Comment: I think the bale would be more prone to drying out, and the potting soil you "save" isn't there for the top-most layer of roots (which is a lot of the roots, for many plants) to grow in. I suspect this would work better [with some different problems like bale (lack of) integrity] with straw that's already partway to decomposing. But, I can't say I've tried it either way since straw is a relatively high-priced option around here (not enough grains being grown to make it an excess.)

Comment: I just read up on this technique.  Your idea sounds reasonable to me.  I think you could also be more frugal with the potting soil by preparing transplants since apparently you don't need the potting soil unless you're direct seeding. / Have you considered grow bags?

Answer (score 1):

Nutrients.

The plants should start fine, but will need added manure or something soon.

I have tried this technique one summer for tomatoes, with success.

In my arid area the point of this technique is that the straw holds moisture so very well.